# Using scaling arguments to determine relationships between Sobolev spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I was looking up how to find relationships between Sobolev spaces and I came across [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17736/way-to-memorize-relations-between-the-sobolev-spaces) post on MO in which the first comment talks about a scaling procedure for understanding the relationships:

> To find the right values of k,p,r,a, I was taught to use scaling
>   arguments. Take a nice enough singularity for the function inside the
>   domain, and make it worse and worse, and compare how the norms change.
>   This usually lets you solve for the appropriate parameter (and if it
>   doesn't it tells you there is something special about that embedding).
>   For unbounded domains you can do the same thing, and this often shows
>   why certain embeddings cannot exist (handling singularities both
>   inside and at infinity is hard).

Other answers also mentioned this scaling approach, which I have never heard of, with one comment saying:

> Comparing the behavior of the different Sobolev norms for a compactly
>   supported family of functions converging to a Dirac delta function is
>   indeed the simplest way to figure out these inclusions. In general,
>   understanding how things behave under rescalings is extremely useful
>   but, as far as I know, rarely mentioned in print. It seems that you
>   have to learn about it by word of mouth or stumble onto it yourself.
>   Physicists and chemists also use this often and call it "unit
>   analysis".

So does anyone here know of this scaling approach? If so could you give a worked example for some specific function, so somebody (like myself) who is new to Sobolev spaces can learn how to apply it and gain a better understanding of these spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Yet another term: I think of these as *homogeneity* arguments.

A simple example (has to be simple, I don't know much about Sobolev spaces): You know that if $f$ is a function on the line and $f'\in L^2$ then $f\in Lip_{1/2}$. Are there any other $Lip_\alpha$ spaces for which this is true? No.

Suppose $$\sup_{x\ne y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}\le c||f'||_2$$(that's the $L^2$ norm). For $\lambda>0$ let $$g(x)=f(\lambda x).$$Replacing $f$ by $g$ in that inequality leads to $$\lambda^\alpha\sup_{x\ne y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}\le c\lambda^{1/2}||f'||_2,$$or $$\sup_{x\ne y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}\le c\lambda^{1/2-\alpha}||f'||_2.$$If $\alpha<1/2$ you get a contradiction by letting $\lambda\to0$, wihle if $\alpha>1/2$ you get a contradiction by letting $\lambda\to\infty$.

**Bonus** You can also sometimes use homogeneityy arguments to improve inequalities. My favorite example: It's a fact that if $f,f'\in L^2(\Bbb R)$ then $\hat f\in L^1(\Bbb R)$. (Where $\hat f$ is the Fourier transform.) Which is to say $$||\hat f||_1\le  c(||f||_2+||f'||_2).$$

Now replace $f$ by $f(\lambda x)$, look at how all three quantities transform, divide by the power of $\lambda$ you get on the LHS and then choose $\lambda$ to minimize the RHS: You get $$||\hat f||_1\le c\left(||f||_2||f'||_2\right)^{1/2}.$$That's the "homogenized" version of the first inequality.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for. I'm not looking for proofs of something, I'm looking for an example of a specific explicit function $f(x) = ...$ and then "taking a  a nice enough singularity for the function inside the domain, and make it worse and worse, and compare how the norms change".

Comment: @csss If you were telling the truth in your post then yes this is a very simple example of what you were looking for. "I was looking up how to find relationships between Sobolev spaces and I came across this post on MO in which the first comment talks about a scaling procedure for understanding the relationships:
To find the right values of k,p,r,a, I was taught to use scaling arguments. " Like here I use a scaling argument to find the right value of $\alpha$ in a special case of the Sobolev embedding theorem.